# Which event loop for SO_TIMEOUT, CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS and child.keepAlive (server side)?

Tags: java, netty

There are two calls to set options in a ServerBootstrap, option() and childOption(). Which one to use for these options in particular?

When to use one or the other in the general case? What's their difference (option and childOption) and how that relates to eventLoops?

What may I get when something timed out? An exception via fireExceptionCaught()?

Also, does anybody know a way to "force" those timeouts (for testing)?

I didn't found all this in the docs, and I don't find anything browsing netty's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`option()` in ServerBootStrap is inherited from AbstractBootstrap which is applicable when the channel is created i.e. at the time of `connect()` or `bind()`

`childOption()` in ServerBootStrap refers to the ChannelOptions when the channel has been successfully accepted, this means that these property will be applied to a channel once accepted